# Forking jUnit with a selenium test using ant runs tests serially, not concurrently

Tags: java, unit-testing, ant, junit, selenium

I have an Ant task that runs a batch of test cases that I have written, which runs perfectly fine... except Ant seems to be ignoring the `fork="true"` attribute in the `<junit>` and `<batchtest>` elements.

Here is my Ant task:

```
<target name="run_tests" depends="init">  
    <java jar="${dir.testLib}${seleniumJar}" fork="true" spawn="true"/>  
    <junit fork="yes" haltonfailure="no" printsummary="no">  
        <classpath  refid="test.classpath"/>  
    <batchtest todir="${test.reports}/acceptance/gui" fork="true">  
    <fileset dir="${dir.classes}">  
                <include name="**/*TestCase.class" />  
        <include name="**/*Test.class" />  
        <include name="**/Test*.class" />  
        <exclude name="**/AbstractSeleneseTestCase.class"/>  
    </fileset>  
    </batchtest>    
        <formatter type="xml" />  
    <classpath refid="test.classpath" />  
</junit>  
    <junitreport todir="${test.reports}/acceptance/gui">    
        <fileset dir="${test.reports}/acceptance/gui">  
            <include name="TEST-*.xml" />  
        </fileset>  
        <report todir="${test.reports}/acceptance/gui" />  
    </junitreport>  
</target>
```

It's taking 8+ minutes to run my test cases one-at-a-time, which is entirely way too long. I have noticed other flukes using Selenium, is this just another nuance of using the project?

Here is a synopsis of what is happening:
1. Run Ant task
2. Ant task spawns a thread to run Selenium server
3. Test cases (Selenium and jUnit) are running one-at-a-time
4. A dark cloud lingers over my cube as my keyboard is struck by lightning ;-(

Here is a synopsis of what I want to happen:
1. Run Ant task
2. Ant task spawns a thread to run Selenium server
3. Tests cases (Selenium and jUnit) launch concurrently
4. Bonuses all around and high fives and pat's on the back for everyone!

Comment: How many Selenium Remote Controls are in your Selenium Grid? Or are you running selenium locally?

Comment: But you're not using the Grid are you? See my answer. BTW the Grid can be run locally, you just need to set it up and set up a bunch of RCs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem to me that you are not running a Selenium Grid, that allows you to run tests in Parallel (as many concurrent "threads" as you have Remote Controls registered in the Grid).

Here's more info: http://selenium-grid.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: +1 Grid seems to be a great tool, now just to get approval to use it on our network...

Comment: You can set up a grid locally too and launch the Grid plus the remote controls on your local machine. Where I work we sometimes do that but there's a server that has a Grid and several RCs already up (using different environments).

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I have seen, and done well mind you, is creating a SeleniumFactory. This would be your own class that spawns a new thread every time you need another web browser test. It takes a little work, but well worth the effort.